# Constraints on models with spontaneous symmetry breaking

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gravity, quantum-gravity, symmetry-breaking

As I understand it, one of the loopholes of the [Coleman-Mandula theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coleman%E2%80%93Mandula_theorem) is that models with spontaneous symmetry breaking (SSB) escape its scope. Is it therefore right to say that a quantum field theory where gravity would emerge from SSB is not invalidated by the Coleman-Mandula theorem? If so, is there another theorem out there that would constraint/reject the structure of such a model?